# Phono Mobile SDK integration with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phono

Iam trying to integrate Phono Mobile with Phonegap.

I did the following steps:

1. Add the Phono Plugin
   Copy the contents of libs to your PhoneGap libs directory. This includes:
     armeab/libg722.so
     phonogap.jar
     srtplight.jar
2. Copy 'jquery.phono.js' to your PhoneGap 'www' directory and include it in your app (e.g. index.html)
3. Added com.phono.android.phonegap.Phono res/xml/plugins.xml
4. voxeolabs.net,phono.com access origin also added

But Phono object was not being initiated. Please correct me if iam doing anything wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple try links like
    <a href="tel:77777777">Call me!</a>